# Tomcat not accessible from EC2

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have a strange issue, I'm deploying my java web service by creating docker image and running the docker on amazon EC2, When I try to access tomcat I'm getting this error
[image]

However when I try to access web-service running on Tomcat it's accessible 
[image]

Can Someone explain me this strange behavior and how I can resolve this ?

My docker-compose file is here

```
version: '2'
services:
  nlp-server:
    image: nlp-docker-image
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
```

Comment: post your docker run command

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran I'm using docker compose, i have updated question now, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker image I was using for tomcat was executing below commands

```
rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples && \
rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs && \
rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
```

as it was removing default webpages, I was not getting the index page on port 8080